# Applying animation through jquery class change

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a sticky css menu which becomes semi-transparent to allow the text to be seen through it. I've added a `:hover {opacity:1;}` to make it opaque when the user hovers over the menu, however, its quite a 'course' change; it would be great to animate these transitions, both when first going transparent and then when going back to opaque.

The way I've made it work is by using jquery to add a `fixed` class to the body tag when the window position is beyond the height of my header div. You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wright_jamie/sTCqq/).

I assume the hover transition is a css3 animation, but I haven't been able to get it to work so far. The initial transition caused by adding the class - I don't even know where to start!

Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution**
CSS3 solution taken and modified from the answer marked below. I moved the transition effect from `.fixed header nav` to `header nav`. This results in the animation working when the `fixed` class is added or removed. Updated solution here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wright_jamie/veDU3/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the specific part of your CSS to

```
.fixed
{
    header nav
    {
        transition: 0.5s opacity;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s opacity;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        opacity:0.6;
        width:100%;
        &:hover{opacity:1;}
    }
}
```

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTCqq/2/) for demonstration

Comment: This seems spot on and I'm not sure why I didn't try that. My only query is the opposite to my comment on @Mooseman - does it require the transition effect to be within the `:hover`? It appears to work fine in Chrome without it.

Comment: You only need to specify the transition for an element/class once in you CSS (unless you override it later) `transition: 0.5s opacity; -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity; -moz-transition: 0.5s opacity;` specifies that whenever the opacity of said element/class changes, it should be in a 0.5 seconds transition

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
body.fixed nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    opacity:0.6;
    transition: 1s opacity;
    -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
    -moz-transition: 1s opacity;
    width:100%;
}
body.fixed nav:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transition: 1s opacity;
    -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
    -moz-transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sTCqq/1/

Comment: Is there a reason for adding the transition to the `nav:hover` as well as the `nav`? I notice that Ejay's version seems to also work without these additional 3 lines.

Comment: @user1972982 It doesn't have to be on the `:hover. But you can specify a different transition (e.g., `3s ease` instead of `1s`) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine jQuery's `.hover()` and `.animate()` methods to do this:

```
$('header').hover(function(){
   $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1 }, 1000);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.6 }, 1000);
});
```

[**Jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/kjNdh/)

Comment: The OP is looking for a CSS3 transition.

Comment: The OP tagged the question as `jQuery` as well, and it's "assuming" it has to be done CSS3, it doesn't say it's a requirement...